# Find (possibly) rotated bounding rectangle

Tags: python, opencv, contour, rectangles

Is there any way I can use either `cv2.boundingRect` or something similar to find a bounding rectangle for an image when it may be rotated?

I have images of squarish randomly rotated shapes and want to find the bounding rectangle's four corner locations.

Starting image example:

[image]

My goal is to find the corner coordinates of the bounding rectangle:[image]

Comment: Have you read the opencv docs for fitting rectangles?

Comment: Some of them.  Any links in particular?

Comment: I think [this](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) is exactly what you want to do, right?

Comment: Thanks, actually started on that page but failed to see the rotated rectangle part.